# Connecting sqlite database to firebird

Tags: firebird

Below command used for connecting database through Firebird SQL.

```
CONNECT "C:\Users\vkaja\Desktop\testing_mysql\newdb.db"
```

In `newdb.db` file Schema, data are dumped from SQLite.

Here `newdb.db` has read-write permission. But error projected here is not a valid username and password.

> Statement failed, SQLCODE = -902

Comment: Try googling that SQLCODE and tell us what it means.

Comment: SQLCODE < 0, execution was not successful. @J.Chomel

Comment: kv, You must show more research effort, please. But thanks for editing.

Comment: After doing some research, I found that with file-extension of `.fdb`, `.gdb` are used for firebirdSQL. But for file extension like  `.db` are not used by firebirdSQL. I am curious to know if this is possible. If yes, It would help for my project.

Comment: "gdb" is standart for Interbase files.  "fdb" is standart for Firebird database files. But firebird database file extension may be any other. For example "db" or "xxx" and Firebird will open it.

Comment: @ValMarinov is it possible to open `.db` file extension through firebird ?

Comment: Firebird doesn't care about the extension of the database file. `fdb` is 'standard', and `gdb` is historical. Your problem is one of authentication.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird doesn't care about the extension of the database file. `fdb` is 'standard', and `gdb` is historical, but it could be anything. However the database you are connecting to must be a Firebird database. You can't just open a database file from a different database system (eg SQLite).

Your problem is one of authentication: you are trying to authenticate without a username + password combination, and if you haven't set the appropriate environment variables, it means Firebird tries to authenticate with an empty user and password, which doesn't exist for your Firebird install. In general you also get this error if you use a username and password that is not known to Firebird.

But even if you fix the authentication problem, you would immediately get a different error: invalid database (or similar), because the file is not a Firebird database.

Comment: How can I reset SYSDBA for firebird. I don't know the password SYSDBA .

Comment: @kvk30 Tip: you could have asked this as a separate question. The default password is `masterkey` (or for Firebird 2.5 and earlier: actually `masterke`). If you don't know the sysdba password you can either reset it with a different user with the `RDB$ADMIN` role (2.5+), or you need to replace the security database (`security2.fdb` for 2.x, `security3.fdb` for 3.x) with one from a clean Firebird install (where it has the default password), or from a Firebird install where you know the password.